# Counting the occurence of numpy.array object in a list of numpy.array objects

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

If I have a list:

```
a = [np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([1,1,1]), np.array([1,1,1])]
```

How to do something like, `a.count(np.array([1,1,1])`? This throws:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Is there a function similar to `.count()`?

Comment: you can do `len(a)` with return length

Comment: What you have in this example  is a Python list of numpy objects.

Comment: `count` is using `==` teat, which for arrays is `element-wise`, resulting in the ambiguity error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.array_equal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) with `sum` on generator:

```
>>> sum(np.array_equal(x, [1,1,1]) for x in a)
3
```

Answer (score 1):

Or map `np.array_equal` and apply `count` to the result

```
map(lambda x: np.array_equal(np.array([1,1,1]),x), a).count(True)
```